# Custom ListView getView() method nullPointerException when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I have a custom listview I am using with a custom adapter. When the app opens initially the first few items are shown properly. However, when I start to scroll down, I get a nullPointerException in the getView() method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

    View vi = convertView;

    if (item.Type.equals("Homework")) {

        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_homework, null);

        ImageView imgThumbnail = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.homework_imgThumbnail);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.homework_txtTitle);
        TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.homework_txtSubTitle);

        imgThumbnail.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
        txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
        txtSubTitle.setText(item.SubTitle);
    }
    if (item.Type.equals("Study")) {

        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_study, null);

        ImageView imgThumbnail = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.study_imgThumbnail);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.study_txtTitle);
        TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.study_txtSubTitle);

        imgThumbnail.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
        txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
        txtSubTitle.setText(item.SubTitle);
    }
    if (item.Type.equals("Project")) {

        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_project, null);

        ImageView imgThumbnail = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.project_imgThumbnail);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.project_txtTitle);
        TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.project_txtSubTitle);

        imgThumbnail.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
        txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
        txtSubTitle.setText(item.SubTitle);
    }

    return vi;
}
```

and it comes in any of the three instances of the line

```
imgThumbnail.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
```

I have looked at other SO questions on this but have not understood exactly what is going on.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you double check that `findViewById` on `R.id.homework_imgThumbnail`, `R.id.study_imgThumbnail` and `R.id.project_imgThumbnail` doesn't return null?.

Comment: Post your logcat. Check the line which logcat told you there is a NPE.

Comment: @epsilondelta Can you please check if the question was answered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to re-use the wrong type of view.

When you scroll down you might receive a `convertView` which was created with, say, the `R.layout.item_row_homework` layout, but the item you have to draw at `position` corresponds to a different type, say, `"Project"`.

Try to use the method `View.setTag` to pass the view type information and check it before reusing it. In case the type is different, you'll probably need to inflate a new view.

As long as you are using a custom adapter, a better approach would be overriding the `getItemViewType(int position)` and `getViewTypeCount()` methods to define the different view types supported.